# Calculate NDVI using Python

Tags: python, arcpy

I know that the NDVI equation is

```
NDVI = (NIR — VIS)/(NIR + VIS)
```

I'm trying to calculate it using python. I've got this so far:

```
inRaster = ('Landsat.tif')
out_NDVI_file = ('NDVI.tif')

red = arcpy.Describe(inRaster+'/Band_3')
NIR = arcpy.Describe(inRaster+'/Band_4')

num = arcpy.sa.Float(NIR-red)
denom = arcpy.sa.Foat(NIR+red)
NDVI = arcpy.sa.Divide(num, denom)

NDVI.Save(out_NDVI_file)
```

but i get this error message,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\abc\def.py", line 32, in <module>
    num = arcpy.sa.Float(NIR-red)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'geoprocessing describe data object' and 'geoprocessing describe data object'
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I just did this but we have a sensor to measure the two bands so we get values from that ... are these some heatmaps or something?

Answer (score 4):

If you replace

```
red = arcpy.Describe(inRaster+'/Band_3')
NIR = arcpy.Describe(inRaster+'/Band_4')
```

with

```
red = arcpy.sa.Raster(inRaster+'/Band_3')
NIR = arcpy.sa.Raster(inRaster+'/Band_4')
```

your script should work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The following script calculates NDVI from 4-band NAIP imagery, where band 4 = nIR and band 3 = Red.  You need the spatial analyst extension for this.

Keep in mind that Landsat TM Band 4 = nIR & Band 3 = Red and Landsat 8 Band 5 = nIR and Band 4 = Red.   [USGS Reference](http://landsat.usgs.gov/band_designations_landsat_satellites.php)

```
# Calculates NDVI from multispectral imagery

import arcpy, string

from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import*

arcpy.CheckOutExtension("spatial")

env.workspace = r'C:\Your\workspace'

input = r'C:\Your\raster.tif'

result = "outputName.tif"

# You may need to change the band combinations.  
# This is for 4-band NAIP imagery or Landsat TM.
NIR = input + "\Band_4"
Red = input + "\Band_3"

NIR_out = "NIR.tif"
Red_out = "Red.tif"

arcpy.CopyRaster_management(NIR,NIR_out)
arcpy.CopyRaster_management(Red, Red_out)

Num = arcpy.sa.Float(Raster(NIR_out) - Raster(Red_out))
Denom = arcpy.sa.Float(Raster(NIR_out) + Raster(Red_out))
NIR_eq = arcpy.sa.Divide(Num, Denom)

NIR_eq.save(result)
```